# Moving a radio button to the right

Tags: css, radio-button

[image]

```html
<div class="row">
  <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input type="radio">
        <label for="Employee">Employee</label>
     </div>
  <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input type="radio">
        <label for="Employer">Employer</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to move buttons and labels to the right to align the below text boxes.

How can I move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<style>

/* Remove default paddings, margins around the elements */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

</style>


<div class="row">
  <div style="text-align:left;">
        <input type="radio">
        <label for="Employee">Employee</label>
     </div>
  <div style="text-align:left;">
        <input type="radio">
        <label for="Employer">Employer</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text".>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text".>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. Do you think radio buttons cannot be placed at the front?

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: The only thing I need is just moving the radio button and label to the right because I would like to align with the below boxes.

Comment: oh, I changed my solution. The text input field may have some default margin and padding. So, first of all, we need to remove those, after that add margin-left to the wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

In this case(looks like hardcoding with only 2 divs), you can do it using :last-child selector in CSS.

Here's the CSS-

```
.row {
    div:last-child {
        padding-left: 20px; //or any other of choice
}
```

If you want it for variable inputs, etc., please update your question, OP!

Comment: Sorry for making you confused. I updated for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use **display:-webkit-box;** I hope that solves your problem.

```css
.row{
display:-webkit-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input type="radio">
        <label for="Employee">Employee</label>
     </div>
  <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input type="radio">
        <label for="Employer">Employer</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for making you confused. I updated to help you better understand what I asked.